# facebook api :: how to get the user ID with FBJS & FBML?

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml, fbjs

how to get the user ID with FBJS & FBML ?

thanks a lot

Comment: We are not going to work for you. Did you read the docs? Do you have code? Did you actually try something? Downvote.

Comment: @metrobalderas .... code for what? i read the doc ... i read a lot but no hope !! i'm not asking for the code .. i'm asking for hints ... and thanks i don't want you to work for me !!

Comment: Why don't you post what you have actually tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This:
First define your constants and:

```
   $config = array(
            'appId'  => APP_ID,
            'secret' => APP_SECRET,
            'domain' => DOMAIN,
            'cookie' => true
                );
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $uid = $facebook ->getUser();
    $me = $facebook ->api('/me');
```

Please see the facebook.php class for functions and arguments.
Very good and detailed tutorials are [here](http://thinkdiff.net/)